# truncating a field value in a SQL select

Tags: mysql, sql

In a SQL statement, how do you limit the returned value of a text field char length to a certain size?

Tried so far-

```
select len(mytextfield,30) from table
```

Comment: SubString : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the [SUBSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) function.

`SELECT SUBSTRING(mytextfield, 1, 30) FROM Table`

(This is assuming SQL Sever / T-SQL; you didn't specify a database engine.)

Comment: don't know why I got a -2 down vote. Not that i care but just weird. but anyway, it's mysql. I'm sorry for not including it in the original question. Now I tagged the q with mysql.

Comment: @AverageJoe - `SUBSTRING` and `LEFT` should work with mySql as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
select left(mytextfield,30)
```

I am not positive, but I think the substring function does not work against the TEXT datatype.

Comment: +1 from me - but from MSDN's `SUBSTRING` documentation - "Returns part of a character, binary, text, or image expression."

Comment: I can't recall right now what the problem was, it might be a SQL 2000 thing.  There are definitely things you can't do with TEXT, one of the reasons that VARCHAR(max) comes in handy.